# Qt Video Recorder

Tags: c++, qt, video, ffmpeg

I am trying to create a video recorder with Qt. What I did so far was taking a screenshot of a rectangle on the screen and save it. At the end I use ffmpeg to get a video file out of the images.

I connected a timer's signal `timeout()` to my custom slot which takes the snapshot and saves it to my tmp folder. The timer has an intervall of 1000 / 30. That should be 30 times per second. But 1000 / 30 is a little bit more than 33 milliseconds so I cannot really get 30 fps. It's a bit more.

I recorded a youtube video with my recorder and everything was smooth but a little bit faster / slower depending on the intervall.

So my question basically is how do I get really 30 / 40 / 50 / ... fps?

Comment: If you use multiple threads for instance one to copy and one to analyze the may be you get better performance. Also it depends on your processor.

Answer (score 2):

1. Start a [QElapsedTimer](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qelapsedtimer.html) when you start the capture.
2. When you are done capturing a frame (at the end of your snapshot slot), multiply the **next** frame number by the approximate frame duration (a double precision floating point value) in milliseconds (e.g. for 30 fps, it is `~33.33333333333`, but don't write that - write `(double)1000/30`). Call this value `next_timestamp`.
3. Call [`elapsed()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qelapsedtimer.html#elapsed) on your QElapsedTimer. Call this value `current_timestamp`.
4. Call the static function [`QTimer::singleShot()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtimer.html#singleShot) to sleep for `next_timestamp - current_timestamp`. Set the slot argument to your snapshot slot again. Note that if the time to sleep is <= 0, you are falling behind; your system can't keep up with the load of capturing that fast.

When `QTimer::singleShot()` fires, your snapshot slot will be called again with some error in timing. However, this error is inevitable under non-realtime operating systems such as Windows and Unix (OS X/Linux/etc). This is because you don't get to decide when code executes - the OS kernel does. On average, though, you will end up with exactly 30 frames per second (assuming your computer can keep up with the load!), because the time elapsed reported by the QElapsedTimer will be quite accurate, and if the system falls behind, it will capture frames more quickly, and if it gets ahead, it will capture frames more slowly.

Comment: A couple things to note. First Screen capture in Qt is VERY slow and inconstant. So it may be hard to get the exact frame rate you want. I would recommend that you use variable frame rate and set the timestamp for every frame. So even if you miss your target frame rate the video will still playback perfectly.