# FFMPEG API - Recording video and audio - Syncing problems

Tags: c++, qt, audio, video, ffmpeg

I'm developing an app which is able to record video from a webcam and audio from a microphone. I've been using QT but unfortunately the camera module does not work on windows which led me to use ffmpeg to record the video/audio.

My Camera module is now working well besides a slight problem with syncing. The audio and video sometimes end up out of sync by a small difference (less than 1 second I'd say, although it might be worse with longer recordings).

When I encode the frames I add the PTS in the following way (which I took from the [muxing.c](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/muxing_8c-example.html) example):

- For the video frames I increment the PTS one by one (starting at 0).
- For the audio frames I increment the PTS by the `nb_samples` of the audio frame (starting at 0).

I am saving the file at 25 fps and asking for the camera to give me 25 fps (which it can). I am also converting the video frames to the `YUV420P` format. For the audio frames conversion I need to use a `AVAudioFifo` because the microfone sends bigger samples than the mp4 stream supports, so I have to split them in chuncks. I used the [transcode.c](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.2/transcode_aac_8c-example.html) example for this.

I am out of ideas in what I should do to sync the audio and video. Do I need to use a clock or something to correctly sync up both streams?

The full code is too big to post here but should it be necessary I can add it to github for example.

Here is the code for writing a frame:

```
int FFCapture::writeFrame(const AVRational *time_base, AVStream *stream, AVPacket *pkt) {
    /* rescale output packet timestamp values from codec to stream timebase */
    av_packet_rescale_ts(pkt, *time_base, stream->time_base);
    pkt->stream_index = stream->index;
    /* Write the compressed frame to the media file. */
    return av_interleaved_write_frame(oFormatContext, pkt);
}
```

Code for getting the elapsed time:

```
qint64 FFCapture::getElapsedTime(qint64 *previousTime) {
    qint64 newTime = timer.elapsed();
    if(newTime > *previousTime) {
        *previousTime = newTime;
        return newTime;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Code for adding the PTS (video and audio stream, respectively):

```
qint64 time = getElapsedTime(&previousVideoTime);
if(time >= 0) outFrame->pts = time;
//if(time >= 0) outFrame->pts = av_rescale_q(time, outStream.videoStream->codec->time_base, outStream.videoStream->time_base);

qint64 time = getElapsedTime(&previousAudioTime);
if(time >= 0) {
    AVRational aux;
    aux.num = 1;
    aux.den = 1000;
    outFrame->pts = time;
    //outFrame->pts = av_rescale_q(time, aux, outStream.audioStream->time_base);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to give the frames (audio and video) real timestamps. Create a function that returns the elapsed time since you started the capture in milliseconds (an integer). Then set `time_base` for each stream to `{1,1000}` and set `pts` of each frame to the return value of your function. But be careful: you can't have a timestamp that is <= a previous timestamp. So you will need to drop frames if you get several all at once (or write another mechanism for dealing with this situation).

Taken from my longer answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23231515/272601).

Example using `QElapsedTimer` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23595059/272601).

Comment: Should I set one QElapsedTimer for both streams? Or one for each? And I need a "previous timestamp" for each stream, right? Also, making each stream to {1,1000} that means how many fps? And how can I convert that? (the user should be able to choose, if the camera allows).

Comment: This seems to be working for the video but not for the audio. As the audio stream always stays with a time_base of {1 sample_rate} even if I change it to {1, 1000}. The first pts end up negative and the audio doesn't play or plays completely off.

Comment: Yes, ffmpeg will sometimes change the time_base to some other rational. In that case you have to convert ("rescale") the timestamp to the stream's time_base before you set it. Use `av_rescale_q(your_pts, your_time_base, stream_time_base)`. You should use only one QElapsedTimer since it is the master timer for your streams. It keeps your streams in sync based on when your program received the audio and video frames.

Comment: I was using `av_packet_rescale_ts` before saving the pkt. I have added the code on my questions. Both this method and using `av_rescale_q` (see commented code) produce bad quality audio (audio skips and is constantly being cut). Also, seems that for some reason `av_rescale_q` slows down performance. I am not sure about this, but frames slow down a lot (I am showing video on screen as well).

Comment: I've been thinking. My microphone gives me 22050 samples for each frame and the output stream uses 1024, so I am using an audiofifo to store the samples and cutting them in 1024 chunks. Shouldn't I just get the elapsed time the each 22050 and then when I'm cutting the samples calculate how much ms should I add to the elapsed time?